# Функция javascript не возвращает значение

Tags: javascript

```
function IsIntersect ()
{
const enemyLeft = parseInt($('#enemies').css("left"));
const playerLeft = parseInt($('#player').css("left"));
const playerWidth = $("#player").width();
const enemyWidth = $('#enemies').width();

if ((playerLeft + playerWidth >= (enemyLeft * -1) && playerLeft < (enemyLeft * -1) + enemyWidth))
{
    console.log(true);
    return true;
}
else
{
    console.log(false);
    return false;
}
}
```

Дело в том что функция не ретурнит ничего тоесть дело не в работе if`а или чего то ещё, она просто почему то ничего не отдаёт на выход, в чём может быть дело?

Comment: Как Вы проверяете что возвращает функция?

Answer (score 0):

Это синтаксически неверный код. Нажмите кнопку "Выполнить код".

```js
function IsIntersect() {
  const enemyLeft = parseInt($('#enemies').css("left"));
  const playerLeft = parseInt($('#player').css("left"));
  const playerWidth = $("#player").width();
  const enemyWidth = $('#enemies').width();

  // Что значит эта строчка?
  playerLeft, "<", (enemyLeft * -1), "+", enemyWidth, true);

  if ((playerLeft + playerWidth >= (enemyLeft * -1) && playerLeft < (enemyLeft * -1) + enemyWidth)) {
    console.log(true);
    return true;
  } else {
    console.log(false);
    return false;
  }
}
```

---

Функция вызывается? Добавьте перед `if`:

```
console.log(enemyLeft, playerLeft, playerWidth, enemyWidth);
```

Что выводится в консоль?

Comment: Это строчка случайно скопировалась, я исправил.

Comment: if работает так как тот console.log(), который внутри if отображается, а return работать не хочет.

Comment: Очень странно но по-моему дело было в имени функции, как бы странно это не звучало, но после изменения имени на check_intersect код начал работать вполне нормально...

Comment: @a.hatson `return` не может "хотеть" или "не хотеть". Покажите код, который вызывает эту функцию.